# calling return from a function to use in a variable in another function? javascript

Tags: javascript

Im doing a shopping simulator using loops and functions. When the user sets a quantity thru promt this get verify with a function and gives me an number. I want to use that return to calculate the instalation fee related to the amount of product buyed but cant get the fuction to work. It takes the value as 0 or stop working. Any idea?

This is the shopping function

```
const comprarEquipos = () => {  
    // Flujo principal
    let equipo = '';
    let cantidad = 0;
    let precio = 0;
    let totalPedido = 0;
    let seguirComprando = false;

    
do {
    equipo = prompt("¿Que minisplit buscas:? inverter, convencional o alta eficiencia","Ej. convencional").toLowerCase();
    cantidad = parseInt(prompt ("¿Cuantos equipos necesitas?", "Ej. 2"));

    const cantidadComprobada = comprobarCantidad(cantidad) 
    switch (equipo) { 
        case "convencional":
            precio = 4900;
            break;
        case "inverter":
            precio = 7500;
            break;
        case "alta Eficiencia":
            precio = 12000;
            break;
        default:
        alert("Ingresa una opcion de producto valida");
            precio = 0;
            cantidad = 0;
            }

    totalPedido += precio*cantidadComprobada;

    seguirComprando = confirm("¿Deseas seguir comprando?"); 
    }  while (seguirComprando)

    const totalConInstalacion = calcularInstalacion(totalPedido);
    
    return totalConInstalacion;
};
```

and this is the function i used to verify the quantity

```
const comprobarCantidad = (cantidad) => { 
    while (Number.isNaN(cantidad) || cantidad === 0) { 
        if (cantidad !== 0) {
            alert("Debes especificar una cantidad.")
        } else {
            alert("Debes pedir una cantidad superior a 0.")
        }
        cantidad = parseInt(prompt("¿Cuantos equipos necesitas?", "Ej. 2"));
    }

    return cantidad; 
}
```

this is the function to calcutate the instalation fee but doesnt seem to get the quantity right

```
const calcularInstalacion = (totalPedido) => { 
    let cantidadMinisplits = comprobarCantidad(cantidad);
    let solicitaEnvio = confirm("¿Necesitas instalacion"); // 2.1 Aqui le preguntaremos al usuario si quiere envio y ese valor se aloja en la variante solicitaEnvio como true si da OK
    
    if (solicitaEnvio && cantidadMinisplits >= 7) {
        totalPedido = cantidadMinisplits*600;
        alert("Por "+cantidadMinisplits+" equipos el costo de instalación es $"+totalPedido);
    } else if (solicitaEnvio && cantidadMinisplits <= 6 && cantidadMinisplits !== 0) {
        totalPedido = cantidad*1100;
        alert("Por "+cantidadMinisplits+" equipos el costo de instalación es $");
    } else {
        alert("No se cobrara servicio de instalación")
    }

    return totalPedido;

}
```

But the promt asking for confirmation on installtion doesnt show up at all. What am I doing wrong? How cant I get it to work?

I i change the value from cantidadMinisplit to a number, the function works correctly

```
const calcularInstalacion = (totalPedido) => { 
    let cantidadMinisplits = comprobarCantidad(cantidad);
    let solicitaEnvio = confirm("¿Necesitas instalacion"); // 2.1 Aqui le preguntaremos al usuario si quiere envio y ese valor se aloja en la variante solicitaEnvio como true si da OK
    
    if (solicitaEnvio && cantidadMinisplits >= 7) {
        totalPedido = cantidadMinisplits*600;
        alert("Por "+cantidadMinisplits+" equipos el costo de instalación es $"+totalPedido);
    } else if (solicitaEnvio && cantidadMinisplits <= 6 && cantidadMinisplits !== 0) {
        totalPedido = cantidad*1100;
        alert("Por "+cantidadMinisplits+" equipos el costo de instalación es $");
    } else {
        alert("No se cobrara servicio de instalación")
    }

    return totalPedido;

}
```

but calling the validation fuction doesnt work

Comment: With this amount of code posted by the OP, in order to get an understanding of the code itself, the OP should provide variable and function names in their English expressive counterparts (btw didn't -1 since the OP is a new contributor).

Comment: Seems to be a scoping issue. See what happens when you define `cantidad` at the topmost level, and comment out the `let cantidad = 0;` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a scoping issue as Fiddling Away suggested. I also used that suggestion to improve the simulator. Changing `cantidad` did solve the issue, thank you and sorry for not translating the variable names, I will do it for future questions.